# AJAX returns multiple results how to direct user to another page when a specific result is returned?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have multiple results being returned when a PHP function makes a call to a database.
The ajax display the results of those calls in a div element.

How do I direct the user to the next page once I get a specific result from the PHP function?

Right now when I try to redirect the page it loads it into the div where I get the returned messages from.

HTML

```
    <form action="reg.php" method="post">
    <input type='text' id='email'>
           <input type="button" value="Add Email" onClick="loadXMLDoc()">
    </form>

<div id='ajax'></div>
```

ajax

```
function loadXMLDoc(){
    var xmlhttp;
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()  {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)  {
        document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

      }
    }
    
    var a = document.getElementById('email').value;

    
    var email ="email="+a;
    xmlhttp.open("POST","reg.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(email);
    
        

}
```

PHP

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
function emailCheck($email) {
        if($email != null) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            echo ' Please add your email. ';
        }
    }
emailCheck($email);
```

Comment: If you provide your code, it will be much easier for us to try and help your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in JS. Otherwise, the redirect happens and then the JS processes the data received after redirecting. Remember, an HTTP redirect means "What you were looking for can be found here" and not "The browser should load this page in the main window".

```
if (someCondition) {
    location = "http://example.com/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the redirect page is displayed in the div, it's because you make the redirection on the server (in your PHP code).
You must make the redirection in the javascript function witch receive the AJAX response with  "window.location = ..."

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use like below to redirect on other page on success:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)  {
      if(xmlhttp.responseText)
      {
        window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
      }
    
    }
```